# How to expect a meteor error with chai

Tags: unit-testing, meteor, chai

I want to test that my method throws an unauthorized error if called without the proper credentials. How would I do this with chai? I see that chai's examples are

```
var err = new ReferenceError('This is a bad function.');
var fn = function () { throw err; }
expect(fn).to.throw(ReferenceError);
expect(fn).to.throw(Error);
expect(fn).to.throw(/bad function/);
expect(fn).to.not.throw('good function');
expect(fn).to.throw(ReferenceError, /bad function/);
expect(fn).to.throw(err);
```

So I tried

```
let error = new Meteor.Error(UNAUTHORIZED, UNAUTHORIZED_REASON, 'detail');
chai.expect(Meteor.call('addItem', item)).to.throw(error);
```

but this didn't work. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way:

Say you have a method that throws following error:

```
throw new Meteor.Error('unauthorised', 'You cannot do this.');
```

Test for that error using:

```
it('will throw an error', function() {
    assert.throws(() => {

        //whatever you want to run that should throw the error goes here

    }, Meteor.Error, /unauthorised/); //change 'unauthorised' to whatever your error is
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Its `expect(fn).to.throw(Meteor.Error);`

```
  it('Test Meteor Error', () => {
    expect(() => { throw new Meteor.Error('test');}).to.throw(Meteor.Error);
  });
```

Comment: It does work for me. I assume your function is throwing Meteor.Error instead of native Error. I have updated the answer with usage sample.

Comment: thanks. my issue was that i didnt surround my call in a function definition

Comment: Yea, noticed that. Thats why I updated my answer with an example.